# logarithm inequality - change log bases or use the same base

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Please evaluate my solutions.

Find all values of the parameter $\alpha\in R $ for which the following inequality is valid for all $x \in R$ $$1+\log _5\left(x^2+1\right)\ge \log _5\left(ax^2+4x+a\right)$$

The range of values can be expressed in the form of $(A,B]$

I have gathered 2 ways of finding the solution:

> 1)Change log bases

$$\log_5(5) + \log_5\frac{x^2+1}{ax^2+4x+a} >= 0$$

$$\log_5\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} >= 0$$

$$\log_\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}{5} >=0$$

$$\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} >0$$

Got two inequalities

$$ax^2+4x+a > 0 ... (1)$$
$$5x^2+5 >0 ... (2)$$

---

$$ax^2+4x+a > 0 ... (1)$$
Find the discriminant:
$$a=2,a=-2$$

$$5x^2+5 >0 ...(2)$$
$$5x^2>-5$$
$$x>(-1)^\frac{1}{2}$$

My answer is $(2, +\infty)$

---

> 2) solve by using the same base.

$$\log_5(5) + \log_5(x^2+1) >= \log_5(ax^2+4x+a)$$
$$\log_5(5x^2+5) >= \log_5(ax^2+4x+a)$$
Got 3 inequalities:
$$5x^2+5>=ax^2+4x+a ... (1)$$
$$5x^2+5>=0 ... (2)$$
$$ax^2+4x+a >= 0 ... (3)$$

---

$$(5-a)x^2-4x+(5-a)>=0 ...(1)$$
Find the discriminant:
$$16^2-4(5-a)^2$$
$$a = 3, a=7$$

$$5x^2+5 >0 ... (2)$$
$$5x^2>-5$$
$$x>(-1)^\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ax^2+4x+a >= 0 ... (3)$$
Find the discriminant:
$$a=2,a=-2$$

My answer is $$(2,7)$$

---

I know both answers are wrong because the correct one is  $$(2,3]$$
Can we get the correct answer from both ways at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach is much more complicated than necessary, and there are a couple of mistakes.

To rephrase the original problem slightly,
you were to find $A$ and $B$ such that $A < a \leq B$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for the following inequality to be true:
$$1+\log _5\left(x^2+1\right)\ge \log _5\left(ax^2+4x+a\right). \tag P$$

It is correct that
$$\log_5\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} \geq 0 \tag Q$$
is a necessary and sufficient condition for (P) to be true.
Since $\log_5 y = \log_y 5$ **when both sides of the equation are defined,**
your next statement,
$$\log_{\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}} 5 \geq 0, \tag R$$
 is a sufficient condition, but **not necessary:**
in the case where $\log_5\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} = 0,$
the expression $\log_{\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}} 5$ is undefined,
so we cannot say that it is greater than or equal to anything.
In particular, in that case we cannot say that (R) is true,
but nevertheless (Q) and (P) are still true even though (R) is not.

Getting the "$=$" case wrong is not going to hurt you too much in this
question, because here it mainly affects whether you have an open or
closed interval, and you were given which side of the interval is open and
which is closed in the problem statement.
What really hurts you is the next step,
$$\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} \geq 0,$$
which is a necessary **but not sufficient** condition for (P) to be true.
Actually, either the fact that you can take a logarithm
of $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}$ or that you can use it as the base of
a logarithm tells you immediately that
$$\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} > 0$$
(notice there is no possibility of "$=$"),
but merely using positive numbers in the base or parameter of your logarithm
does not guarantee that the result is non-negative;
for example, $log_2 \frac12 = log_{(1/2)} 2 = -1.$
A **sufficient** (and necessary) condition for (Q) and (P) is
$$\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} \geq 1. \tag S$$
Notice that this is already clear from (Q) without needing to do any
change of base, because $\log_5 y < 0$ whenever $y < 1.$

TL;DR: You should never have attempted to write (R); it's not quite
accurate and it's much more confusing to work with than (Q).

Note that $5x^2+5$ is guaranteed to be positive, since
$x^2\geq 0$ for all $x$ and $5 > 0.$
So (S) implies that $ax^2+4x+a > 0$ (otherwise the ratio would be negative),
and we can multiply both sides of (S) by $ax^2+4x+a.$
Therefore either of your two methods, **correctly executed,** gives us the
same three inequalities:

\begin{align}
5x^2+5 &\geq ax^2+4x+a  \tag 1\\
5x^2+5 &\geq 0   \tag 2\\
ax^2+4x+a &> 0  \tag 3
\end{align}

The statement that all three of these are true for all $x$
is a necessary and sufficient condition for (P).

Notice that I have written ($3$) in a stronger form than you did.
(It says $>$ rather than $\geq$.)
This only matters if you need to find out whether each end of 
the interval of your solution set is open or closed.

As you (sort of) observed, if we take the $=$ case of ($1$) we get a quadratic equation,
$$(5-a)x^2-4x+(5-a) = 0, \tag 4$$
whose discriminant is $16^2-4(5-a)^2.$
But you did not say why that matters.
The reason why it matters is that if the discriminant is positive,
then ($4$) has solutions for two distinct values of $x,$
and therefore $(5-a)x^2-4x+(5-a)$ is **negative** for some values of $x.$
That is, it would not be true that $5x^2+5 \geq ax^2+4x+a$ for all $x.$

But simply finding where the discriminant is zero doesn't tell us much
about whether $5x^2+5 \geq ax^2+4x+a$ for all $x.$
In order to know whether ($1$) will be true, we want to know
the value of $a$ for which the discriminant is **not positive,**
and we also need $5-a > 0,$ since otherwise very large positive or negative
values of $x$ will make $5x^2+5 < ax^2+4x+a.$

In other words, we need $5-a > 0$ and we need $4(5-a)^2 \geq 16^2.$
Simplifying, $5-a > 0$ and $(5-a)^2 \geq 64,$
therefore $5-a \geq 8,$ so $a \leq 3.$

In particular, note that if $3 < a < 7$ then the discriminant
$16^2-4(5-a)^2$ is positive and $(1)$ is false for some values of $x.$
So you must not let any part of the interval $(3,7)$ be part of
your answer.
I do not know why you thought the answer should be based on an inequality
involving $a$ and the number $7,$ but if it was a guess, it was a bad guess.

The inequality ($2$) is automatically true for all $x$ for reasons 
already given. Please **do not write** anything like $x > (-1)^{1/2}$;
that inequality **is not true** for any value of $x$
for the simple reason that $(-1)^{1/2}$ is not a real number.

The inequality ($3$) does indeed correspond to a quadratic whose
discriminant is zero when $a = \pm 2.$
Again, however, you did not say why that matters, and you did not say
why you concluded that $a > 2$ rather than $a < -2$ or
$-2 \leq a \leq 2$ or any other condition on $a.$
In fact we need $a$ to be positive in order for $(3)$ to be true
for large values of $x,$ and we rule out $-2 \leq a \leq 2$
because that makes the discriminant non-negative, which implies that
$ax^2+4x+a  = 0$ for at least one value of $x.$

So indeed we do need $a > 2,$ whether or not this was a valid deduction
or a lucky guess on your part.

So altogether, $2 < a \leq 3,$ so $A = 2$ and $B = 3.$

Comment: @Minah My point is that what you just wrote is not entirely correct. It is correct if you write $> 0$ instead of $\geq 0$, but when you write $\geq 0$ you have to consider what will happen in the "$=0$" case. If $\log_5 \frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}= 0$ then $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}=1,$ and you cannot use $1$ as the base of a logarithm, so your logarithm in the second inequality becomes undefined.

Comment: Hmm yes I actually wanted to edit the question but time ran out and it became permanent. I'll delete it now.

Comment: the question is asking about $$log_5\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} >= 0$$

The change of base would become $$\frac{1}{\log_\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}{5}} >=0$$

Our new log is a denominator therefore $$\log_\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}{5} >0$$

Now just evaluate the base of our new log it becomes $$\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} > 1$$ (since a log base must be greater 1) and it's also an equality hence we can evaluate the inequalities. 

$$5x^2+5>ax^2+4x+a$$
$$5x^2+5>0$$ 

$$ax^2+4x+a>0$$ Now my is my statement correct for change of log bases?

Comment: Is it logical to evaluate inequalities on the log base?

Comment: @Minah Your longer comment still begins with the same mistake I mentioned earlier. You are handling the "$>$" part of $\geq$ OK but you are not handling the "$=$" case. If we follow your logic we would conclude that $a<3,$ whereas the correct answer says $a\leq 3.$ Moreover, you now say "a log base must be greater 1." **That is not true.** The reason that $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}\geq1$ (not necessarily $>1$!) is because your logarithms would be negative if $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}<1.$

Comment: It _is_ OK to construct inequalities using the base of the logarithm, it's just that as with all inequalities, $>$ is not the same as $\geq,$ you have to beware of things like division by zero or other illegal operations, and so forth.

Comment: "a log base must be greater 1." **That is not true**. Why do you say that? I think log base cannot be negative numbers and it cannot be 1 and 0. Take for example $1^x=10$ is undefined so is $0^x=10$

Comment: also $\log_5(x)=0$ means $5^0=1$ Thus it is valid to say $log_5\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} = 0$ given that $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} =1$

Comment: A log base can be between 0 and 1. For example, $\log_{0.2} 5 = -1.$ That is why I said it is not true that every base "must" be greater than 1. And yes, certainly if $\dfrac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} =1$ then it is correct to write $log_5\dfrac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} = 0,$ but in that case it is _not_ correct to write $\dfrac{1}{\log_\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}{5}}\geq0.$ The logarithm in the denominator is not even defined then, for as you pointed out, you cannot have a logarithm base $1.$

Comment: Ok I got it I need to consider the numbers in between 0 and 1 hence the log base is $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a} >= 0$ but not 0 and 1. Thus the inequalitties are $$5x^2+5>=ax^2+4x+a$$

Comment: Right, that's what we conclude from the fact that we can use this number as a base of a logarithm. Then we look at further facts and we conclude from _those_ that the number actually cannot be less than 1.

Comment: I still think that the first 3 equations (not in the original question but in this comment section) is correct with the signs. Only the fourth needs to change to >= 0.

Comment: The inequality with $>0$ will be _necessary,_ of course (since you can't have something $\geq 1$ if it is not $>0$), but it is not _sufficient._ The fact that the logarithm in (Q) _exists at all_ tells us that $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}>0,$ but (Q) says more than just that the logarithm exists: it also says the value of the logarithm is non-negative. Given that fact, and the fact that the base is greater than 1, we know that $\frac{5x^2+5}{ax^2+4x+a}\geq 1.$ This is important, because that's how we get inequality (1).

Comment: And yes, the fourth inequality should be $\geq,$ as you say, but it is not valid to conclude this from the second and third inequalities, because they cannot say anything useful about the $=$ case. The way to get the correct fourth inequality is directly from the first one.

Comment: You see how complicated this gets with keeping track of when it is correct to infer $\geq$ and when you can only do $>.$ That is why I recommend to use a relatively simple method with fewer steps. It makes fewer places where mistakes can creep in.

Comment: Thank you very much your explanation on (P) and (Q) needed to be >=1 is very important to find inequalities result from changing base.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $1+\log_5\left(x^2+1\right)\geq\log_5\left(ax^2+4x+a\right)$ can be reduced to the two following inequalities: \begin{align}
(5-a)x^2-4x+(5-a)\geq0, \\
ax^2+4x+a>0.
\end{align} First we'll solve the first inequality. It's clear that the parabola must open upwards, hence $5-a>0$ or $a<5.$ Now, the parabola attains its minimum at $x=2/(5-a),$ hence the minimum is $$\frac{4}{5-a}-\frac{8}{5-a}+(5-a)$$ and satisfies \begin{align}
\frac{4}{5-a}-\frac{8}{5-a}+(5-a)\geq0, \\
4-8+(5-a)^2\geq0, \\
(5-a)^2\geq4, \\
5-a\geq2, \\
a\leq3.
\end{align} Now for the second inequality. It's once again clear that the parabola must open upwards, hence $a>0.$ This time, the parabola attains its minimum at $x=-2/a,$ hence the minimum is $$\frac{4}{a}-\frac{8}{a}+a$$ and satisfies \begin{align}
\frac{4}{a}-\frac{8}{a}+a>0, \\
4-8+a^2>0, \\
a^2>4, \\
a>2.
\end{align} Putting it all toghether yields that $a\in(2,3].$